# Magento2 : Override core files vendor/magento/module-catalog/Pricing/Price/TierPrice.php

Tags: magento2, overrides, catalog, products, tierprice

How to override

`vendor/magento/module-catalog/Pricing/Price/TierPrice.php` ?

in **magento 2**

Answer (score 0):

In Magento2 You can overwrite using below code

create di.xml in your module

```
<xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Price\TierPrice" type="Vendor\Module\Pricing\Price\TierPrice" />
</config>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Can you please share complete code to override the TierPrice ?

Answer (score 0):

Create custom module **app/code/Vendor/ModuleName** and override that class using dependency injection, in reference [Override Classes in Magento 2](http://inchoo.net/magento-2/overriding-classes-magento-2/%0A) you will find detailed step info to do this job :

important part is "To make sure we have the right order of module dependencies, etc/module.xml should have defined module sequence ..."

For Module sequence read below dev docs article.

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/build/module-load-order.html